# Including Python standard libraries in your distribution

Tags: python, licensing

For a project I'm working on I need to include some Python modules that come standard with the Python SDK because the platform I am targetting (to be precise, PyS60) does not include these modules. Are there any licensing issues I need to address? Do I need to include the PSF license in my project?

My project is licensed under Apache 2.0.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about licensing or legal issues, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274963/questions-about-licensing/274964#274964) and [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139804/can-licensing-questions-ever-be-on-topic) for details, and the [help] for more.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According to the [PSF License FAQ](http://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonSoftwareFoundationLicenseFaq):

> Can I bundle Python with my non-open-source application?
>
> Yes. Unlike some open source licenses, the PSF License allows Python to be included in non-open applications, either in unmodified or modified form.

The FAQ goes on to explain about third-party module licensing.

In effect, I think the answer is 'Yes'.

DISCLAIMER: IANAL.

Answer (score 7):

The python license is very open.

[Python License](http://www.python.org/download/releases/2.4.2/license/)

- Python is absolutely free, even for
  commercial use (including resale).
  You can sell a product written in
  Python or a product that embeds the
  Python interpreter. No licensing fees
  need to be paid for such usage.
- The Open Source Initiative has
  certified the Python license as Open
  Source, and includes it on their list
  of open source licenses.
- There is no GPL-like "copyleft"
  restriction. Distributing binary-only
  versions of Python, modified or not,
  is allowed. There is no requirement
  to release any of your source code.
  You can also write extension modules
  for Python and provide them only in
  binary form. However, the Python
  license is compatible with the GPL,
  according to the Free Software
  Foundation.
- You cannot remove the PSF's copyright
  notice from either the source code or
  the resulting binary.