# Copying License dependencies for Pyinstaller

Tags: python-3.x, pyinstaller

This is related to [a previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60054742/licenses-for-dependencies-with-pyinstaller/60054816#60054816) but is more specifically about implementation.

To recap the previous question, I have a Pyinstaller app with 3rd party dependencies. As @AKX answered, the license text from those dependencies should be included in the Pyinstaller distribution.

**Pyinstaller makes no attempt to handle this**.

Therefore I am looking for a way to automate this process.

My project uses a virtual env, and the dependencies are located at:

```
\venv\Lib\site-packages
```

One option would be to recursivley search through this folder, and find any files that match a specific pattern (e.g `LICENSE.txt`). **However**, some of the packages do not ship with a license file, and instead just name the license in their metadata. For example, I am using `openpyxl`

there is a folder

```
\venv\Lib\site-packages\openpyxl-3.0.0-py3.7.egg-info
```

which contains a `PKG-INFO` file. This lists the license (MIT/Expat) but does specifically contain the license text. In this case would it be acceptable to include a copy of the `PKG-INFO` file, or some copy of the standard MIT license text?

Has anyone faced this issue and implemented a solution in an elegant way? @AKX ([in the previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60054742/licenses-for-dependencies-with-pyinstaller/60054816#60054816) linked to a tool which outputs the license information as text/json etc.. but doesn't actually attempt to move any files.

Answer (score 4):

If anyone has a similar question, this is the solution I implemented, which seems to work pretty well for me:

At the top of my `.spec` file I added this

```
matches = ["LICENSE.txt","METADATA","PKG-INFO"]
lics = []
print("Find 3rd party dependency license files")
for root, dir, files in os.walk("venv\Lib\site-packages"):
    for file in files:
            if file in matches:
               src = f"{root}/{file}"
               dest = f"licenses/{os.path.basename(root)}"
               lics.append((src,dest))
               print(f"\tLicense file: {root}/{file}")
print(f"{len(lics)} dependency licenses found. Copying to /license folder in distribution")
```

which builds a list of tuples containing the source of the license or metadata, and the destination to copy it to in the distribution.

To do the actual copying, I made use of the `datas` keyword in the `Analysis` object, and simply expanded the list using `*lics`.

This could be adapted to include more `matches` or be smarter and parse the files, or something like that. It is also probably a bit wasteful and copies some files multiple times, but this seems like a minimal overhead for a tiny text file.

If anyone sees this and has suggestions or comments then I'd be happy to be further informed on this subject!

Comment: This looks very useful to me, thanks! A few comments: 1. My `venv` used a different file structure, so I had to change the path to `"venv/lib"`. 2. I don't see why any list expansion would be necessary, since the `datas` keyword expects a list of tuples (`datas=lics`). Maybe you could add a code sample of how that looks for you, also to make clear that it also needs to be done.

Comment: 1. Sounds sensible. 2. I have other tuples already in my datas, so I need to expand the list.